# Sybase AdoNet4 AseClient v16.x (Client unable to establish a connection)

Tags: c#, ado.net, sybase, sap-ase

I have a Sybase client app, which is written in C# using ADO.Net 4.0. Code has reference to Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll assembly file.

On my (DEV)box, app works perfectly and no issue.

When I move this app, along with Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll file on to a Windows 2008 server (#1), and run the app.. it is unable to get a successful connection to Sybase DB! It is throwing below error.

> Client unable to establish a connection

Checked stack trace message, it not useful.

> at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.Open() at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection.Open()

Connection string is made up of
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Port=1234; Database=dbname; Uid=username; Pwd=password; ConnectionIdleTimeout=nnn;

Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is Server(#2) and it is pingable and no issue there (response time<1ms TTL=255).

Comment: No one face this type of issue? or Sybase & ADO.Net combo is not popular??

Comment: Hey, the supplied answer actually worked for me - are you still having problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `Charset=iso_1` (or the appropriate charset) to your connection string. This resolved my issue.

e.g.:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Port=1234; Database=dbname; Uid=username; Pwd=password; ConnectionIdleTimeout=nnn;
```

would now be:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Port=1234; Database=dbname; Uid=username; Pwd=password; ConnectionIdleTimeout=nnn;Charset=iso_1;
```